# Tracert latency is higher then ping latency

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

I performed a test using `tracert` to a specific host and I found that I have latency of `600ms` between one hop, but when I try to ping the destination I am getting 100ms.

How is it possible that ping latency is not the sum of all the latency of the hops? I may miss something here, can someone explain why is it that and may add some information about the way ping and `tracert` calculate the latency?

Comment: Answred on ServerFault - [windows - Why do tracert latencies not add up to ping latency? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/584601/why-do-tracert-latencies-not-add-up-to-ping-latency)